# How to Fix Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a [wordpress website](https://www.kullu-manali.co.in/kullu-manali-tour-packages).But I run into the following error.

> custom-js.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
>     at HTMLDocument. (custom-js.js:2)
>     at c (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
>     at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
>     at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: have you added the reference of carousel library?

Comment: Wordpress disables the `$` alias by default, so you need to call `jQuery(...).carousel(...)` instead. Since your script has more `$` calls, you can also wrap the entire thing in `(function($) {` and `})(jQuery);` See here: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Maybee 46 script tags in the page is a bit too much? I think you are loading carousel but then load jQuery again so the carousel extension is removed.

Comment: Please don't use external links they are prone to break. Add the relevant parts into the question so it remains helpful even after the external content is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to include the carousel library? I found you are including "owl carousel", which is initialised differently.

Owl carousel, according to [their documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html), uses `$element..owlCarousel(optionsObject)`, not `$element.carousel(optionsObject)`.